What is the last day to leave Malaysia on a 90-day visa if I arrived 13 Feb 2024?
I want to be sure I don't overstay in Malaysia. I arrived February 13, 2024 at 6pm on a 90-day visa exemption. What is the exact date and time I need to leave by? How can I calculate this? It would be very helpful.

Generally the day you arrive and the day you leave both count as full days, so if I count correctly this means you should leave by May 12. It's rarely a good idea to push these things all the way to their limit....
